# Passing a dereferenced pointer to a structure as a function argument

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

If a pointer to a structure, inside one function, is dereferenced and passed as an argument to another function how does one access the structure's members inside that function?

For instance, a pointer to a structure is passed to a function like this:

```
main_logic_tick(&settings);
```

Inside the `main_logic_tick` function, the pointer is dereferenced and passed as an argument to another function (i.e. `tick()`):

```
void main_logic_tick(Settings* settings)
{
    //...
    state_machine.tick(*settings);
}
```

How do I access members of the stucture `Settings` via the `settings`-variable inside the tick()-function above? Is it a call by value or a call by reference? And finally, how should the function prototype for the tick()-function look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I access members of the stucture Settings via the settings-variable inside the tick()-function above? Is it a call by value or a call by reference? And finally, how should the function prototype for the tick()-function look like?

`tick()` can accept the `Settings` object by value or by reference. It sounds like you want it to accept its argument by reference -- that you want to be able modify the object and have the modifications be visible two functions upstream. For that, you would use:

```
void tick(Settings& settings);
```

Inside `tick` you would use the usual syntax for accessing members of a reference -- using the dot (`.`) operator.

```
settings.member = new_value;
```

Comment: Won't the struct be a copy? Or will the values of its members be accessible outside the function where they are set?

Comment: @AbdelAleem, No. Yes. :)